# How to display item count of specific folder in list

Tags: list, workflow, folder, item

I have a list, which has some columns including title and URL. URL column directs to specific folder related to list item. I want to add one more column in list, which would display items' count of that folder. How I can do this? There is no workflows on SP2010 platform which would count items in folders. Any simple sollutions?

**UPDATE** It would be fine just to have a choice column with values is related folder is empty or not.

**UPDATE2**
I'm currently using this workflow in my document library where related fodler are stored:
If Current Item: Item child count equals 0 then update item in MyList to FALSE(text column field)
If Current Item: Item child count not equals 0 then update item in MyList to TRUE(text column field)
Workflow triggers then item is changed or created.

The problem is that I get an error: An error has occurred in MyWorkflow

Answer (score 7):

SharePoint contains a hidden Site Column called `ItemChildCount`. This Site Column stores the calculated number of child items that the folder contains.

> Note: It does not include the number of subfolders in this count nor
>   does it work recursively and pick up the item counts of subfolders

---

To add the `Item Child Count`, edit the desired view on your document library and look for the Item Child Count field and check it

[image]

Save the changes to your view and then go back to your document library. You should now see the number of items in each folder
[image]

Comment: Yes, I found it, but I need to display this item count in other list which as URL column which has link to folder. AND I need to see this folder's item child count in list, NOT in document library where folder is stored.