# JSLink to get the number of files under folder

Tags: sharepoint-online, jslink

we need to display the number of files for each folder in a library

how can we achieve this through JSLink?

please help me with some code samples

Comment: This could help you https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/110338/how-to-display-item-count-of-specific-folder-in-list

Comment: Are you using classic views or modern?

Comment: we are using classic views as of now